# How can I listen my all components with only one event?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

Here is the problem,
I have 3 textfield, 3 button and 1 label. Their text are text1, text2 text3, but1,but2,but3.

I give you an example about what I want to do; When I double click on a button, button will change label's text as button's text. I mean when I double click to but2, label's text should be but2.

I can do this with that code;

```
        MouseAdapter ml = new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                if (me.getClickCount()==2) {

                 jLabel1.setText(jButton1.getText);

                }
            }
        };
        jButton1.addMouseListener(ml);
```

So It works but it works only for jButton1. I have to write different mouseListener's for all components(textfields and jbuttons). How can I do this with one listener? or one event ? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`MouseEvent#getSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) ... although, to be honest, if you're using `JButton`s you shouldn't be using a `MouseListener`, but `ActionListener` instead.  Also, generally speaking, most users won't double click a `JButton` as it's not intuitive for them to do so, buttons only need a single click to activate

Remember, buttons can be activated by the keyboard as well, which `MouseListener` won't be notified about

Comment: I tried getSource,also I tried getComponent but I can't use methods like getText or setText, I guess I have to cast it to JButton or JTextField, still its not my answer :(. Actually I'm a student and its my project so I should do it :p do you have any idea ?

Comment: Actually, you did just answer your own question `if (me.getSource() == jButton1) {...}` you could also use `if ("What ever the text f jButton 1 is".equals(me.getActionCommand())) {...}`